# Linux Partition with SSD and HDD

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm

I'm currently setting up my server and I don't get how to choose Disk 1 and Disk 2 for the partition. vg0 should be the HDD and vg1 the ssd.

Maybe you can help me how to set up such in this syntax.

That's how it currently looks: [image: http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/dtsoqr4cwkv9d.png]

Comment: What distribution is this?

Comment: Ubuntu 14 trusty, today released

Answer (score 1):

Start showing the logical volume informations with `lvdisplay` command. 
Under `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/` you'll see which disk is which brand... try out these commands and tell us more... see my [wiki page](http://www.swami-muktananda.org/pipo/wiki/doku.php?id=linux:lvm&s[]=lvm) about that to have more infos. Late but hope it helps